# Como recuperar um valor de dentro de uma tag no XML?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Possuo uma tabela chamada `SPDNFE` com uma coluna `DsXML` que contém todo conteúdo de um `Xml`.

## Query:

```
SELECT top 1  SPDNFE.DsXML  FROM SPDNFE
where SPDNFE.CdIdNFe = 'NFe32170710490181000569550040001475221002513963'
```

Retorno desta consulta é um `Xml` como segue abaixo.(*Apenas uma parte*)

```
<vol><qVol>3</qVol><esp>VL</esp><pesoL>43.000</pesoL><pesoB>43.000</pesoB></vol>
```

Como busco somete o que tem dentro da tag `<qVol>` que seria o número `3`.

Existe algum meio de `substring` ou algo do gênero ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type)

> Executa um XQuery contra um XML e retorna um valor de tipo SQL. Esse
>   método retorna um valor escalar. Você geralmente usa esse método para
>   extrair um valor de uma instância `XML` armazenada em uma coluna,
>   parâmetro ou variável de tipo xml . Desta forma, você pode especificar
>   consultas SELECT que combinam ou comparam dados `XML` com dados em
>   colunas `não-XML`.

## E como ficaria meu `SQL` @Marconi?

Seu `SQL` deve estar assim:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<vol>
    <qVol>3</qVol>
    <esp>VL</esp>
    <pesoL>43.000</pesoL>
    <pesoB>43.000</pesoB>
</vol>'  

SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/vol/qVol/node())[1]', 'int')  
SELECT @ProdID qVol
```

## [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68b32/1067)

Para mais informações acesse o *Link* do começo da resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar o query()...

```
declare @XML xml

set @XML = '<vol><qVol>3</qVol><esp>VL</esp><pesoL>43.000</pesoL><pesoB>43.000</pesoB></vol>'

select @XML.query('/vol/qVol')
```

Você deverá fazer um CAST do seu campo para o tipo xml, caso seja varchar ou nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Se a sua coluna for do tipo `NVARCHAR` ou `VARCHAR` você pode usar um `LIKE` na consulta:

```
SELECT SPDNFE.*
  FROM SPDNFE
 WHERE SPDNFE.DsXML LIKE '%<qVol>3</qVol>%'
```

---

> [`LIKE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179859(v=sql.120).aspx)
>
> Determina se uma cadeia de caracteres específica corresponde a um padrão especificado. Um padrão pode incluir caracteres normais e curingas. Durante a correspondência de padrões, os caracteres normais devem corresponder exatamente aos caracteres especificados na cadeia de caracteres. No entanto, os caracteres curinga podem ser correspondidos a fragmentos arbitrários da cadeia de caracteres. O uso de caracteres curinga torna o operador LIKE mais flexível que o uso dos operadores de comparação de cadeias de caracteres = e !=. Se qualquer um dos argumentos não for do tipo de dados de cadeia de caracteres, o Mecanismo de Banco de Dados do SQL Server o converterá no tipo de dados de cadeia de caracteres, se possível.

---

O caractere `%` dentro do campo que está sendo procurado no `LIKE` indica que pode haver qualquer conteúdo no local dele. No nosso exemplo estamos dizendo que a tag `qVol` pode estar localizada em qualquer local do texto.

Comment: é bom ideia desde que a coluna seja `varchar`. Como ele não mencionou, sua reposta seria a melhor opção, mas se a coluna for do tipo `xml`, seria melhor o `exists` com o xpath do xml. Só para deixar como alternativa

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloquei um apontamento com relação a isso

Comment: Tentei mas fica muito lenta a consulta como vare a tabela inteira que tem muito registro fica inviavel com like.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer que o retorno da consulta seja apenas o que está dentro da *tag*; sendo assim, acredito que a forma mais simples é usar [replace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql) pra remover as *tags* do resultado:

```
select replace(replace(SPDNFE.DsXML, '<qVol>', ''), '</qVol>','')
```