# Como extrair em uma string a data-hora de um determinado campo XML - Query SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, query, sql-server-2012

Boa tarde!

Pessoal, na minha tabela log tem um campo chamado logdescricao e nesse campo ele armazena várias expressões. Por exemplo:

```
<log expressao="7085"><par traduzir="N">André Mariano da Silva</par><par traduzir="N">Gestores Boavista</par><par formatarData="S"><par traduzir="N">21/09/2017 09:19:00</par></par><par traduzir="N">Teste</par></log>
```

Queria saber, como posso retirar a partir do que ele me traz, somente a data 21/09/2017 09:19:00. OBS: O número de caracteres não tem tamanhos padrões, por isso, dificultando o uso de uma substring, por exemplo. Como poderei realizar isso?

Comment: é um problema, já que todas as tags tem o mesmo nome

Comment: Seria isso? [Como recuperar um valor de dentro de uma tag no XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227093/como-recuperar-um-valor-de-dentro-de-uma-tag-no-xml/227100#227100)

Comment: Esse campo grava o mesmo numero de tags ?

Comment: Sim @MarconcilioSouza , só vai mudando a data

Comment: Bom, veja se a ideia da resposta ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que vi a data está dentro de outra tag "par", que pode ser selecionada com o código abaixo.

```
 DECLARE @myDoc xml 

SET @myDoc = '<log expressao="7085">
<par traduzir="N">André Mariano da Silva</par>
<par traduzir="N">Gestores Boavista</par>
<par formatarData="S">
<par traduzir="N">21/09/2017 09:19:00</par>
</par>
<par traduzir="N">Teste</par>
</log>'  

    select  @myDoc.query('(/log/par/par)')
```

Se quiser retornar somente o valor, utilize a função **value()**

`SELECT  @myDoc.value('(/log/par/par)[1]', 'varchar(30)')`

Comment: Só adiciona a informação de que se tiver mais alguma tag com `par` dentro de `par` não vai funcionar.

Comment: ôpa amigo @Alexandre Cavaloti, bem, nessa consulta deu certo, porém, somente na data fixa q vc setou, porém, tenho outros registros nesse mesmo esquema, porém, a data muda constantemente, ou seja, tenho outros registros q retornam a data de hoje, por exemplo. Como retorno os outros registros retornando somente a data?

Comment: Na última linha que adicionei só é retornado a data. O número _[1]_ indica que está retornando o primeiro nó nessa situação.

Comment: Considere o código e não necessariamente o padrão, se sempre a data estiver num segundo nível de _<par>_ pode considerar este padrão, caso não pode ser necessário incrementar o XQuery com um filtro. O importante é entender o padrão ou os atributos para filtrar.

Answer (score 1):

Se sua string contiver apenas uma DATA e essa data estive dentro do seu `<par formatarData=`, você pode usar o [CHARINDEX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) para verificar a posição que ela esta e obter-la através do [SUBSTRING](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql).

```
declare @texto varchar(1000) = '<log expressao="7085"><par traduzir="N">André Mariano da Silva</par><par traduzir="N">Gestores Boavista</par><par formatarData="S"><par traduzir="N">21/09/2017 09:19:00</par></par><par traduzir="N">Teste</par></log'

select SUBSTRING(@texto, CHARINDEX('<par formatarData=',@texto) + 40, 19)
```

Agora se você tiver mais de uma DATA, então, teoricamente você precisaria de um loop para verificar a posição da próxima data.