# Busca Informação em campo XML em SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, select

Eu preciso efetuar uma busca dentro de um campo onde armazena um XML

O XML é de um CT-e e nele tem uma série de tags e preciso encontrar um dado dentro de uma tag específica.

Abaixo a estrutura da Tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O XML possui a seguinte estrutura e dentro dele o campo que eu preciso consultar é a tag "Chave".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possivel uma busca, onde eu retorno o campo ChaveAcesso mas na clausula WHERE eu coloque pra buscar o valor da chave  que estou procurando dentro do xml?

Muito obrigado

Comment: o valor é o mesmo ?

Comment: Não. O valor do campo "ChaveAcesso" é o identificado do documento chamado CT-e. Já a tag chave, dentro do XML é referente a chave da nota fiscal que está sendo transportada pelo CTe.

Comment: você quer fazer um filtro para buscar o valor dentro do xml, isso vai ficar caro.

Comment: [Como recuperar um valor de dentro de uma tag no XML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227093/como-recuperar-um-valor-de-dentro-de-uma-tag-no-xml/227100#227100)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O SQLServer dispõe de algumas funções para extrair dados de tabelas com campos xml.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type
https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/lendo-xml-no-sql-server-iniciando-com-xquery/
https://pessoalex.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/extraindo-informacoes-de-arquivo-xml-para-o-sql-server/

Fiz um teste criando uma tabela contendo um campo id e outra para armazenar o XML:

```
create table cte (
    id INTEGER IDENTITY,
    campo_xml XML
)
```

Depois incluí alguns registros com o xml na mesma estrutura abaixo, somente modificando a chave do CTE:

```
insert into cte (campo_xml)
values (Cast(
    '<cteProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte" versao="2.00">
        <protCTe versao="1.03">
            <infProt>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <verAplic>SP_PL_CTe_103d</verAplic>
                <chCTe>99999994018888000349570040000165560001999999</chCTe>
                <dhRecbto>2011-07-05T14:42:56</dhRecbto>
                <nProt>135110011494444</nProt>
                <digVal>eFWH/VAzwb+MQuBSp9NWZdzXdL4=</digVal>
                <cStat>100</cStat>
                <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso do CT-e</xMotivo>
            </infProt>
        </protCTe>
    </cteProc>' as XML))
```

Por último fiz a consulta para retornar o registro corresponde a chave no XML:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte')
select * 
from cte
where 
    campo_xml.value('(/cteProc/protCTe/infProt/chCTe)[1]', 'varchar(100)' )='99999994018888000349570040000165560001999999'
```

Para agilizar a consulta dos dados podem ser criados índices para esse campo XML, já que você vai precisar apenas de uma parte dos dados. Na documentação da Microsoft existem algumas informações sobre o uso e a sintaxe para a criação:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-indexes-sql-server
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-xml-index-transact-sql

Comment: boa não sabia dessa.]

Answer (score 2):

Você teria que fazer algo de tipo

```
DECLARE @document varchar(max);  
SELECT @document = '<Header><Header><Username>testeyyytttyyyyyy</Username><chave>ef4dbf9f4b6c80fe03671cc476b29636</chave></Header></Header>';  

DECLARE @tabela TABLE
(
  id int,
  xml nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @tabela VALUES (1, @document);
SELECT @document = '<Header><Header><Username>testeyyytttyyyyyy</Username><chave>ef4dbf9f4b6c80fe03671cc476b29637</chave></Header></Header>';  
INSERT INTO @tabela VALUES (1, @document);
SELECT @document = '<Header><Header><Username>testeyyytttyyyyyy</Username><chave>ef4dbf9f4b6c80fe03671cc476b29638</chave></Header></Header>';  
INSERT INTO @tabela VALUES (1, @document);


SELECT * FROM @tabela AS t
WHERE 'ef4dbf9f4b6c80fe03671cc476b29636'  = 
(SELECT SUBSTRING(t.xml, (select PATINDEX('%<chave>%', t.xml) + len('<chave>')), 32))
```

Note que no WHERE estou passando uma chave para ser localizada no seu xml ***ef4dbf9f4b6c80fe03671cc476b29636***

É necessário que você encontre ela dentro do seu xml para que depois faça o filtro

```
(SELECT SUBSTRING(t.xml, (select PATINDEX('%<chave>%', t.xml) + len('<chave>')), 32))
```

Estou usando o SUBSTRING que recebe 3 parâmetros o primeiro é seu campo xml da sua tabela o segundo o index inicial ,ou seja, o que tive depois do `<chave>` o terceiro parâmetro e o tamanho da string que você quer, aqui estou assumindo que você tem uma string sempre do tamanho de 32 caracteres, caso seja diferente veja como buscar o index final.

Comment: Só lembrando essa consulta dependendo da quantidade de registro vai sair cara a busca. talvez seria melhor criar um novo campo com o valor da chave com um index no campo. e fazer um update com esse select.